# Как найти пустой div с помощью xpath без индексов

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

Как найти с помощью xpath пустой div в div'е с классом "branch2"(БЕЗ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ ИНДЕКСОВ)

```
 <div>
    <div>
        <div class="branch1">
            <div>
                <div></div>
                <div>Параметры систем</div>
                <div value="SYSTEM_PARAMS"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="branch2">
            <div>
                <div>Статистика систем</div>
                <div value="SYSTEM_STATS"></div>
                <div></div> <!-- Вот этот div -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//div[@class="branch2"]//div[not(@*) and not(child::*) and not(normalize-space())]
```

Ищутся пустые div'ы (без атрибутов, вложенных элементов и содержимого) внутри div'а с классом branch2.

Comment: Без детей можно `count(*)=0`.